# Make a textbox fill all the available space in container but there must be some place left for a fixed button

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm making an aspx page that is meant to be viewed inside an iframe. The page exists of a simple gridview and on top of the page is a textbox and a button. (search function)

I want the button on the right side of the textbox so the textbox AND the button together fills all the available width. The button has a fixed width. Only the textbox has a dynamic width.

I've been looking on this but still didn't found a sollution for this CSS problem. Does anyone of you know what css that i have to use to solve my problem so it looks like the scheme below?

```
[TEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEXTBOX] [BUTTON]
/----------------------------------------------\
|----------------------------------------------|
|-----------------GRIDVIEW---------------------|
|----------------------------------------------|
|----------------------------------------------|
|----------------------------------------------|
\----------------------------------------------/
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find something *really* elegant, but I got 3 options for you.

Set your textbox width with javascript.

```
textBox.width = textBox.Parent.width - button.width
```

use a 100% (or almost) width textbox in **absolute** and put the button over it

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <input type="button" style="float:right" value="search or what not" />
  <input type="text" style="width:100%; position:absolute; top:0px; z-index:-1 " />
  <br style="clear:both" />
</div>
```

use a table

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr><td>
        <input type="text" style="width:100%" />
    </td><td width="100">
        <input type="button" value="search or what not" />
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks! i used the table version because i was already trying something with tables but no i got it working with your help!